# Fastest way to do S3 copy from one bucket to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a file which is encrypted in KMS key1 in my bucket1. I need to transfer it to bucket2 and encrypt it using KMS key2. I was initially using the GetObject and the PutObject API. But this takes a long time for larger files (5GB and beyond). Also I am performing this task on a lambda thus the timeout is 15 mins.

I tried using the TransferManager download API but it requires a File and I run into the below error. I was planning to do a multi-part download and then do a multipart upload. As per my understanding because of my requirement to decrypt my file using key1 and then encrypt my file using key2, I cannot use a multi part copy as it uses the same Amazon S3 client.

````
TransferManager sourceTransferManager = TransferManagerBuilder
                    .standard().withS3Client(sourceS3Client).build();
            GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(srcBucket, srcKey);
            File modelFile = File.createTempFile("BigFile", "gz");
            logger.log("Starting download");
            Download download = sourceTransferManager.download(getObjectRequest, modelFile);
            download.waitForCompletion();
            sourceTransferManager.shutdownNow();
            logger.log("Finishing download");

            logger.log("Downloaded the object, let's upload it");
            //For a decrypted object, the content length in metadata still has the encrypted length
            //Set the content length to the unencrypted-data-length

            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(destS3Uri.getBucket(), destS3Uri.getKey(), modelFile);
            transferManager = TransferManagerBuilder
                    .standard()
                    .withS3Client(destS3Client)
                    .build();
            Upload upload = transferManager.upload(putObjectRequest);```

aused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to store object contents to disk: No space left on device
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.downloadToFile(ServiceUtils.java:314)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.DownloadCallable.retryableDownloadS3ObjectToFile(DownloadCallable.java:275)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.DownloadCallable.downloadAsSingleObject(DownloadCallable.java:92)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.AbstractDownloadCallable.call(AbstractDownloadCallable.java:102)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.AbstractDownloadCallable.call(AbstractDownloadCallable.java:40)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.downloadToFile(ServiceUtils.java:309)
... 8 more
````

Comment: Are both buckets in the same AWS account?

Comment: Have you tried simply using the `CopyObject()` method? It copies an object, including between buckets, without needing to download/upload. As long as you have permission to use the KMS key associated with the source object, it will be able to read the object. Then, you would specify the KMS key for the destination object.

Comment: Both my buckets are in different account and in different regions too. I am unable to copy it using the same s3 client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CopyObject()` method to copy objects between buckets, even if the buckets are in **different accounts** and **different regions**. ***There is no need to download/upload the object!***

Let's say you are copying from `Bucket-A` in `Region-A` that belongs to `Account-A` to `Bucket-B` in `Region-B` that belongs to `Account-B`.

There are two ways to do it:

**Pull method**

- Let's say there is an IAM User (`User-B`) in `Account-B`
- Add a Bucket Policy to `Bucket-A` that permits `User-B` to **List/Get** from the bucket
- As `User-B`, send the `CopyObject()` command to Amazon S3 in `Region-B` (the destination bucket "pulls" the object from the source)

**Push method**

- Let's say there is an IAM User (`User-A`) in `Account-A`
- Add a Bucket Policy to `Bucket-B` that permits `User-A` to **List/Put** to the bucket
- As `User-A`, send the `CopyObject()` command to Amazon S3 in `Region-B` (the destination bucket "pulls" the object from the source) and make sure to specify the **ACL** as `bucket-owner-full-control`. This allows the destination bucket (owned by a different account) to 'own' the copied object. This is important!

I prefer the 'pull' method because it does not require the additional specification of the Access Control List (ACL), since `Account-B` owns the object it copies (as opposed to `Account-A` sending the object to `Account-B`).

If this is a one-off activity, I would recommend using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) since it is very easy to use. However, if you need it to run more often, it might be worth coding it up.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the KMS bit. You would also need to grant access to the IAM User to use KMS in the other account. This will make it slightly more difficult. I haven't tried it myself. Let us know if it works! See: [How to Copy Encrypted S3 Objects Across Accounts – 1Strategy](https://www.1strategy.com/blog/2018/10/30/how-to-copy-encrypted-s3-objects-across-accounts/)